# Creating separate scripts to run after separate reboots

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, init

I am wanting to run multiple scripts after boot up.  When the machine boots up, one script would run and force a reboot.  Then, after the reboot, another script would run and then reboot.  Need this to happen about four times.  Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You could save the current status of the system into a log file. Then a master script could read the last written status and run conditionally a certain script of the bundle.

Comment: I like that answer a lot.  That's an interesting way to go about this.  So, I'm thinking I could then just take all four scripts and combine into one with a conditional response for each set of commands.  how would I create the log file so that it changes after each reboot and then how would I refer to the log file?  Sorry.  Really trying to wrap my head around the idea of automation using bash scripts.  I really appreciate the direction

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer with example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You could save the current status of the system into a log file. Then a master script could read the last written status and run conditionally a certain script or function. Here is an example of such script:

```bsh
$ cat ~/status-reboot.sh
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

STATUS_LOG="$HOME/our.status.log"

# Determinate whether the log file exists ? get the status : set status0
if [[ -f $STATUS_LOG ]]
then
        CURRENT_STATUS="$(cat "$STATUS_LOG")"
else
        CURRENT_STATUS="stage0"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS : $(date)"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS" > "$STATUS_LOG"
        # You could reboot at this point,
        # but probably you want to do action_1 first
fi

# Define your actions as functions
action_1()
{
        # do the 1st action

        CURRENT_STATUS="stage1"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS : $(date)"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS" > "$STATUS_LOG"
        exit # You could reboot at this point
}

action_2()
{
        # do the 2nd action

        CURRENT_STATUS="stage2"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS : $(date)"
        echo "$CURRENT_STATUS" > "$STATUS_LOG"
        exit # You could reboot at this point
}

case "$CURRENT_STATUS" in
stage0)
  action_1
  ;;
stage1)
  action_2
  ;;
stage2)
  echo "The script '$0' is finished."
  ;;
*)
  echo "Something went wrong!"
  ;;
esac
```

Here is how it works within the command line:

```bsh
$ ./status-reboot.sh
stage0 : Thu Aug  6 22:45:29 EEST 2020
stage1 : Thu Aug  6 22:45:29 EEST 2020

$ ./status-reboot.sh
stage2 : Thu Aug  6 22:45:33 EEST 2020

$ ./status-reboot.sh
The script './status-reboot.sh' is finished.

$ ./status-reboot.sh
The script './status-reboot.sh' is finished.
```

I think it should work without problem with crontab entry as this:

```
@reboot sleep 15 && "$HOME/status-reboot.sh" >> "$HOME/our.progress.log"
```

- Please use full paths to the commands into your scripts used with crontab.

Reference: [tldp.org - Using case statements](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_03.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @pa4080.  I'll try this out.  i really appreciate the time you put into this explanation.

Comment: You are welcome, @noobuntu :)