# Using exec bash in bash script

Tags: bash, execute-command

I am trying to set up my environment using a bash script. One of the things that I need to do in the bash script is to restart bash, which I use `exec bash` for. Is there a way to have the script continue after the `exec bash` command? Currently it does not run any command after that command.

Comment: Do you mean you want to execute command after command?                                                         like;  in bash: $ exec bash && echo command2 goes here ?

Comment: Restarting bash means *to me* that the old bash process is terminated and only the new bash is running. Do you want the old bash process to continue? Or do you want the new bash to perform the commands, that you want to run after it has been started?

Comment: I'd want the new bash to perform the commands

Comment: I will try to paraphrase @sudodus's comment. `exec bash` will substitute the current PID with a new bash shell. So you need something like `exec my_next_script.sh`. In this scenario [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1265053/566421) could be adpted according to your needs. However, I suppose you just need to source some environment file, like `. ~/.bashrc` (or `source ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Perhaps take a step back and explain *why* you need to restart bash part way through a script (just so we can make sure it's not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) )

Comment: Explain **what** you are trying to do. The **how** is wrong, but if we know what, then we can probably help.

Comment: I am restarting bash after I run the command conda init to have anaconda start in my bash shell (because it does not start automatically on the server that I am on)